# Angular Routing not working when adding ID as a parameter in URL

Tags: angular, routes

new to Angular here. I have the following in my app.module.ts

```
RouterModule.forRoot()
{
...
      { 
        path : "posts/:id",
        component: PostprofileComponent 
      },
      { 
        path : "posts",
        component: PostsComponent 
      },
...
}
```

The following is redirecting correctly to **PostprofileComponent**.

http://localhost:4200/posts/2

However this link does not... it redirects to **PostsComponent**.

http://localhost:4200/posts?id=2

Shouldn't they behave the same? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What are you doing wrong? You're expecting them to behave the same. They are not the same.

Comment: Query parameters in Angular allow for passing optional parameters across any route in the application. Query params are different from regular route parameters, which are only available on one route and are not optional (e.g.: `/posts/:id`).

Answer (score 1):

In your `RouterModule`:

```
RouterModule.forRoot()
{
...
    {
        path : "posts/details/:id",
        component: PostprofileComponent
    },
    {
        path : "posts/details",
        component: PostprofileComponent
    },
    {
        path : "posts",
        component: PostsComponent
    },
...
}
```

Usage example using **query params**: (More info [here](https://alligator.io/angular/query-parameters/))

`this.router.navigate(['/posts/details'], { queryParams: { id: '2' } });`

URL: http://localhost:4200/posts/details?id=2 **return to =>** `PostprofileComponent`

---

Usage example using **route params**:

`this.router.navigate(['/posts/details', '2']);`

URL: http://localhost:4200/posts/details/2 **return to =>** `PostprofileComponent`

---

then http://localhost:4200/posts **return to =>** `PostsComponent`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Leandro! I see now that i misunderstood the concept a bit. Now it makes more sense...

Comment: If this response resolve your question, please close the post =)

Answer (score -2):

The second option is using url query parameters while the first option is using angular routing parameters.

i.e. using this:

```
   this.router.navigate(['/posts', '2']);
```

would result in your first route http://localhost:4200/posts/2

and then this:

```
this.router.navigate(['/posts'], { queryParams: { id: '2' } });
```

would result in second route http://localhost:4200/posts?id=2

Comment: But at `RouterModule` you have to differentiate between 2 components, `PostprofileComponent` and `PostsComponent`

Comment: right...so the http://localhost:4200/posts/id=2 route is going to the PostsComponent page because it's technically routing to /posts with an optional param while he's expecting it to go to posts/2 when that's an entirely different route.